# void* ptr = &func; compiles with msvc without any diagnostic but both gcc and clang rejects it

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, function-pointers, pointer-conversion

I am learning C++ using the book "C++ Primer" by Stanley. In particular, the section about "pointer conversions" says:

> a pointer to any nonconst type can be converted to `void*`

---

After reading this I wrote the following program that compiles with msvc **without any diagnostic** but is rejected by both gcc and clang. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7MEcxosv5)

```
int func()
{
    return 4;
}
int main()
{
    void* ptr = &func; //works with msvc but rejected by clang and gcc
}
```

As you can [see](https://godbolt.org/z/W4T7c88qT) the above program works with msvc but gcc says `error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'void*'`.

I want to know which compiler is correct here. Note that I've used `/permissive-` flag with msvc to make it standard conformant.

Comment: Try `void* ptr = (void*)&func;`.

Comment: Looks like ill-formed to me. The book should say "object type".

Comment: The quote from the book is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: Why the downovtes? I have provided a minimal reproducible example and the question is clear and concise. I am also using good books to understand the concepts.

Comment: @RyanZhang "C" style cast? Are you sure? (Usually hides problems or causes UB)

Comment: Downvote, because this is for sure not a language laywer question. It is either a typo, or bad practice

Comment: @PepijnKramer This is not a typo. I created this based on the quoted reference from the book. Secondly, even compiler(msvc) have not implemented this correctly as it allows the conversion that is ill formed. So this question discovered(or rediscovered) a bug with the compiler and so this definitely needs the language lawyer tag. Third, this is not a production code. It was created to reproduce the issue at hand. So you should not judge the program on whether it is bad or good practice.

Comment: @RyanZhang That's also only conditionally supported (although mandated by POSIX and I don't know an implementation where it is not supported).

Comment: @Alan I mean a typo in the book. And language laywer questions usually require answers that direct to the C++ standard directly

Comment: @PepijnKramer How exactly is asking which compiler is correct not language lawyering? And how could the question possibly be answered without recourse to the standard?

Comment: @user207421 I should not answer while distracted... you're right ;)

Comment: The Windows version of Clang says "implicit conversion between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is a Microsoft extension". So it is apparently a known issue.

Answer (score 5):

The program is **ill-formed** because there is no implicit conversion from a pointer to a **"function type"** to `void*`. The implicit conversion is only allowed if the target is an **"object type"** which `int()` is not. This can be seen from [conv.ptr#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#2) which states:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T”, **where `T` is an object type**, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
> to cv void”. The pointer value (6.8.3) is unchanged by this conversion

Further from [dcl.init#general](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.9.sentence-3):

> Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression.
> A standard conversion sequence ([conv]) is used to convert the initializer expression to a prvalue of the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered.
> **If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed.**
> When initializing a bit-field with a value that it cannot represent, the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined.

(emphasis mine)

Note the emphasis on the word **"object type"**. And since in your code `T=int()` is a *"function type"* there is no conversion from `int(*)()` to `void*` meaning the program is ill-formed and **msvc is wrong in accepting the program without any diagnostic.**