# Workaround for "use of variable before deduction of auto"

Tags: c++, lambda, low-level

I am creating wrapper functions, that modify existing functions (*targets*). The targets are determined at runtime as pointers without type information (`void*`). Each of them has different parameters and return type. The wrapped functions are called from external code, so they have to match the signature of the target.

The basic scheme is like this:

```
bool wrap(void* f, void** t)
{
    *t = magic();  // target determined at runtime as void*
    return true;
}

// define new wrapping function and storage for target
int(*foo_target)(int);

int foo(int data)
{
    return foo_target(data) + 10;
}

auto res = wrap(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&foo), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&foo_target));
```

The `wrap` function is a placeholder, that does all the heavy lifting. For each target I define a wrapper function (`foo`) and a variable to store the function pointer to the target function with the correct type (`foo_target`).

This works, but requires ugly type casts and I have to keep the signatures of `foo_target` and `foo` in sync manually. What I would like to have is something like this:

```
template <class F>
struct wrap
{
    F* target;

    wrap(F&& f)
    {
        target = reinterpret_cast<F*>(magic());
    }
};

static auto foo = wrap(
    [](int data) -> int   // <- signature of the wrapper and target function
    {
        return foo.target(data) + 10;     // ERROR
        // return 10;                     // WORKS
    });
}
```

The single type cast required is hidden in the `wrap` function, and the signature of the target function is in a single place. Of course, this does not work because `foo` cannot be used in the lambda like that.

If I use a common base class, I can make this solution work. However, in this case I need a type cast in every wrapper function and have to define the function signature twice.

```
struct wrap_base
{
    void* target;
};

template <class F>
struct wrap : wrap_base
{
    wrap(F&& f)
    {
        target = magic();
    }
};


static wrap_base foo = wrap(
    [](int data) -> int        // <- signature of the wrapper and target function
    {
        using func = int(int); // <- repeated here
        return reinterpret_cast<func*>(foo.target)(data) + 10;
    });
```

**Edit** The target functions may have different calling conventions. This probably means that I cannot use (non-capturing) lambdas, although I have not had any issues so far.

Comment: A function pointer cannot be converted to `void*`(atleast not portably) See [`void* ptr = &func;` compiles with msvc without any diagnostic but both gcc and clang rejects it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77551776/void-ptr-func-compiles-with-msvc-without-any-diagnostic-but-both-gcc-and-cl/77551822#77551822)

Comment: Even with `reinterpret_cast` it is implementation defined afaik so don't do `reinterpret_cast<void*>(&foo)`

Comment: This is why I need to use `reinterpret_cast`. I have working code for both gcc and clang based on the first and third snippet (see https://godbolt.org/z/f8xKh9TTT). But I would prefer a solution like the second snippet to get rid of the repetitive type casting and redundant type definitions.

Comment: `return foo.target(data)` can't work as type of `foo` hasn't been determined yet. Basically, **`foo.target` requires that `foo` is a complete type.**

Comment: The type of `foo` in the second snippet is to be determined from the initializer but in your case the initializer also depends on the type of `foo` so this seems recursive.

Comment: @user12002570 Yes, exactly. That's why I am asking for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want a recursive-lambda.
One way is a [Y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator), i.e adding `Self` parameter:

```
template <class F>
struct wrap;

template <class Ret, typename... Args>
struct wrap<Ret(Args...)>
{
    Ret(*target)(Args...);
    std::function<Ret(wrap&, Args...)> func;

    template <typename F>
    requires(requires(F f, wrap self, Args... args) {
        f(self, args...);
    })
    wrap(F f) : func(f)
    {
        target = reinterpret_cast<Ret(*)(Args...)>(magic());
    }

    Ret operator()(Args... args) {
        return func(*this, args...);
    }
};

static auto foo = wrap<int(int)>(
    [](auto& self, int data) -> int
    {
        return self.target(data) + 10;
    });
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aMa4Mnsv9)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the signature of the wrapper function must match that of the target. I have clarified this in the question.

Comment: @dliw: Demo added to be more complete. I don't think CTAD can be used here though :/

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it looks like a dead end. I thought I had overlooked an obvious possibility....